# Object.create and inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I'm learning about Object.create and inheritance in JavaScript from an Udemy course and I have a missunderstanding. And I want to ask you if you can help me to understand how it works. Thank you in advance!

For example I have this simple line of code:

```
var Person = function(name, yearOfBirth, job) {
    this.name = name;
    this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
    this.job = job;
};

Person.prototype.calculateAge = function() {
    var age = new Date().getFullYear() - this.yearOfBirth;
    console.log(age);
};

var Athlete = function(name, yearOfBirth, job, olympicGames, medals) {
    Person.call(this, name, yearOfBirth, job);
    this.olympicGames = olympicGames;
    this.medals = medals;
};

Athlete.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Athlete.prototype.constructor = Athlete; 

var objAthlete = new Athlete('Mark', 1990, 'swimmer', 3, 10);
```

I want to ask you if it is mandatory to put this line of code:

```
Person.call(this, name, yearOfBirth, job);
```

Can I change the Athlete constructor with the following code:

```
var Athlete = function(name, yearOfBirth, job, olympicGames, medals) {
    this.name = name;
    this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
    this.job = job;     
    this.olympicGames = olympicGames;
    this.medals = medals;
};
```

I understand why we use Object.create and why we assign the correct value to the constructor property of the prototype, but I don't understand if it is mandatory the line of code.

And another question is about _ *proto* _, I know about prototype and "dunder" proto, but I don't understand it in the following situation.

For example if I write `console.dir(abjAthlete)` I get this output in the console:

[image]

The instructor say that the prototype is Person, and that means that the Athlete function constructor prototype property is the same that Person prototype property. How is that possible because if I write `Athlete.__proto__ === Person.prototype` I receive **false**. I really apreciate any feedback!

Comment: "*The instructor say that the prototype is Person*" - no, the prototype of your `abjAthlete` instance is `Athlete.prototype` as you'd expect. The console just says that this object "looks like a `Person` instance" - because it inherits from `Person.prototype`.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to ask you if it is mandatory to put this line of code:
>
> ```
> Person.call(this, name, yearOfBirth, job);
> ```
>
> Can I change the Athlete constructor with the following code?

Yes, you could, and it would have exactly the same effect. However, you would now have duplicated the initialisation code for `Person`s, and that's a bad practice. [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) and just call the `Person` constructor that already knows how to initialise those properties.